# When i scroll down a DIV that has a background-image, the image doesnt scroll as the div does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to simulate a grid system, so i have a function `set_gridSize" which will set the background-image of the div to a grid.  the output of the function sets the backgroubd image to a base64 encoded string that renders.

```
$.css({"background-image", "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+encode(xml) +")"});
```

so i create this, and it looks create.  the issue though is that when it scrolls, it doesnt scroll the image as well.  I was thinking that it would.

is there something that i am doing wrong?  Is there a concept for this that i am missing to address?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say your problem is. Can you explain or post screenshots please?

Comment: While it is hard to do it with a grid, my goal is to have the image slowly scroll off the page when scrolling in the div in which the background is assigned.  The issue is that the image isnt moving

Comment: Can you post your full code or a jsfiddle please? I don't understand how that would happen without `background-attachment: fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `background-image` property you can't do that, but if you place another `div` inside the original one and set the `background-image` of that one, that would work: [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5CzsG/2/)

Comment: Can this be resolved with using scrollbars in the divs, instead of using the browsers scrollbar as well?

Comment: MMM... i like this answer.  I was really hoping that we could combine these 2 things together in 1 div, but at least WE have an answer that is acceptable.  I just need to look a bit more to see if we CAN get it working with 1 div.  If not then you just won the question.  Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Try using the `background-attachment` property along with `background-repeat`:

```
$.css({
    "background-image": "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+encode(xml) +")",
    "background-attachment": "fixed",
    "background-repeat": "no-repeat"});
```

This will keep the image where it originally started as you scroll the page.

[Example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4E5jt/)

Comment: That is actually the opposite of what i want.  I want to have the image scroll off of the div when the are scrolling

Comment: You really should have clarified that then. "it doesnt scroll the image as well" can be interpreted either way.